# Multiple SELECTs in a complex mysql statement

Tags: mysql, select, store

I made a mysql query that is getting a result set from table A using a value 'x' stored in table B. Right now whenever I need 'x' I need to reSELECT it up to 6 times.

Simplified version of my query looks something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM A WHERE a = (SELECT x FROM B ...) AND b = (SELECT x FROM B ...)-5 AND c = (SELECT x FROM B ...)+7
```

Is there a way to store that value 'x' during the evaluation of my sql statement?
If not, does it make sense to use 2 queries instead (first one to get 'x' and second one with 'x' included in the real statement)?

If you want to see one of my statements, here is an example:

```
    "(SELECT * FROM map WHERE x BETWEEN :x-:sight and :x+:sight AND y BETWEEN :y-:sight+:map_max_y and :map_max_y) /*1.part*/

    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM map WHERE x BETWEEN :map_min_x and MOD((:x+:sight),:map_max_x) AND y BETWEEN :y-:sight+:map_max_y and :map_max_y ORDER BY y LIMIT 225)  /*2.part*/

    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM map WHERE x BETWEEN :x-:sight and :map_max_x AND y BETWEEN :map_min_y and :y+:sight ORDER BY y LIMIT 225) /*3.part*/

    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM map WHERE x BETWEEN :map_min_x and MOD((:x+:sight),:map_max_x) AND y BETWEEN :map_min_y and :y+:sight ORDER BY y LIMIT 225) /*4.part*/";
```

'x', 'y', 'sight' are all stored in the DB and it hurts my eyes to reload them that many times (this is the older version which doesn't load them from DB just yet). And I believe making 2 queries is a bad habit aswell.

Thank you in advance, guys :)

Comment: Mysql does have variables (See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Seems this should help you answer your question yourself?

Comment: `select @x_from_b := x from b`?

Comment: Thank you, I will read that one up. Seems I missed a MySQL lesson :)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql optimizer should be able to detect such duplicated subselect and perform it only once. Just make sure it is really the same select which does not use anything variable from outside, and use EXPLAIN to confirm, that it gets optimized.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Optimization is important for me, so this makes me feel better already. Next step is to improve it's readability :) But I think I know how now

Comment: Readability can be easily improved by putting subselect into variable and then build outter select using this variable (simple string concatenation, no SQL involved at this level).

Comment: I mean (in PHP): `$subselect = "(SELECT ...)"; query("SELECT $subselect AS x FROM ... WHERE $subselect > 10 ORDER BY $subselect");`